# tailwind css with vscode

Tags: html, visual-studio, tailwind-css

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i91uP.png)
how could I get those suggestion when I'm typing

I want to get the suggesting when typing

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities to get the suggestions while writing code using the Tailwind CSS framework:

- the first using their extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss
- the second using GitHub Copilot: https://github.com/features/copilot

Comment: Copilot is not necesary

Answer (score 0):

open the VS code quick open (Ctrl+P) and paste the following command
ext install bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss
And then install tailwind css and the tailwind config file named 'tailwind.config.js' in your workspace
Done it should now add the suggestion
For more details read the article [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss#:%7E:text=Launch%20VS%20Code%20Quick%20Open,following%20command%2C%20and%20press%20enter.&text=Tailwind%20CSS%20IntelliSense%20enhances%20the,%2C%20syntax%20highlighting%2C%20and%20linting.)

Answer (score 0):

you just need install an unocss extendion,
i've tried a few methods,and didn't worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).